# How Do I Upgrade a Show to a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to ilustrate the difficulties in assigning bins to a data set and then running a comparison of the bins against a binomial distribution for all values- n, p. The code I have so far is (mostly thanks to Nasser):

```
Manipulate[Show[Histogram[dataB, {-0.5, 7.5, c}, "PDF"], 
  DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x], {x, 0, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], ImagePadding -> All],
  {{c, 8, "Column Width"}, 0, 4, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{n, 7, "Number Of Quarters"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{p, 0.5, "Fair Coin Toss"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The remaining problem, scaling the number of quarters in the binomial to the width of the X axis. Right now my X axis ranges from 0 to 7.5 in agreement with the range of the numbers in my data set. I think I need two X axes. One to illustrate the range of the numbers in my data set. And a second X axis to illustrate the number of quarters in the binomial ensemble (1 to 20). That's what I think. @Nasser

Comment: What are the variables you want to control with the slider bars?

Comment: what is your control variables? i.e. what are the parameters you want to change? The first question to ask when making a Manipulate is: What do I want to control?

Answer (score 2):

I have replaced your dataA with some live value,

```
Manipulate[{Histogram[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[s, f], 200], {-0.5, 6.5, 1}, 
   "PDF"], DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[a, b], x], {x, 0, 7},
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]}, {a, 1, 10, 1}, {b, 0, 1, .1}, {s,
   0.1, 1, .1}, {f, 0.1, 1, .01}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need additional controls, need to be more specific.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Histogram[dataA, {-0.5, 6.5, 1}, "PDF"], 
  DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x], {x, 0, 7}, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], ImagePadding -> 10],
 {{n, 6, "how many trials?"}, 2, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, .5, "success probabilty?"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :>
  (
   dataA = RandomInteger[{-1, 7}, 100];
   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]